# Changed ***key-certbot.pem file caused server offline

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

**Server**: Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Our sites "crashed" just now due to a certificate issue:

```
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/letsencrypt/keys/0000_key-certbot.pem") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

In the Virtual hosts, we have these lines:

```
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/keys/0003_key-certbot.pem;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[domain]/fullchain.pem;
```

On checking the `/etc/letsencrypt/keys/` folder, I found these results

```
/etc/letsencrypt/keys # ls -la
total 40
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jul  5 15:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Apr 18 10:58 ..
-rw-------  1 root root 1704 Apr 18 11:01 0000_key-certbot.pem
-rw-------  1 root root 1708 Jan 31 14:37 0000_key-letsencrypt.pem
-rw-------  1 root root 1704 Apr 18 11:18 0001_key-certbot.pem
-rw-------  1 root root 1704 Jan 31 14:37 0001_key-letsencrypt.pem
-rw-------  1 root root 1704 Apr 18 11:19 0002_key-certbot.pem
-rw-------  1 root root 1708 Feb  2 11:47 0002_key-letsencrypt.pem
-rw-------  1 root root 1708 Jun 17 12:01 0003_key-certbot.pem
-rw-------  1 root root 1704 Jul  5 15:33 0004_key-certbot.pem
```

The (3) virtual host files were all referencing `0000_key-certbot.pem`, after changing that to `0003_key-certbot.pem` the sites were working again.

How can we prevent the sites from crashing every 90 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While typing this I think I found the solution, I shouldn't have been using

```
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/keys/0003_key-certbot.pem;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[domain]/fullchain.pem;
```

But instead

```
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[domain]/privkey.pem;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[domain]/fullchain.pem;
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: This solved my issue. Maybe I should have paid more attention to the manual!

Comment: I know the feeling :-)

Comment: thanx for sharing. had exactly the same issue :-)

Comment: Glad it helped @kieste !